# Can't parent the mesh with automatic weights

Tags: armature

I just started out blender its been a month, trying out all sorts of things so here i was doing some rigging following tutorials on youtube. i came across a problem which i haven't been able to solve for last couple of days. If anyone can help me out it would mean a lot.
Here's a link to the file ..
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XM-krx5uN-FAF5TWUdxOtL7sxRpKXsw6